# вопросы по поводу работы с жесткими дисками в linux

Tags: linux, многопоточность, железо

Здравствуйте, читаю "Системное программирование" Роберта Лава, он пишет про fsync(), O_SYNC, но не понятно о назначении этих функций...

1. Где необходимы вызовы этих функций? Если б это было нужно всегда, то синхронизация бы была по дефолту установлена. 
   Цитата из книжки.

   > Налицо огромное увеличение издержек, поэтому синхронизированный ввод-вывод следует использовать только при отсутствии альтернатив.
2. Со сколькими параллельными операциями ввода / вывода может работать жесткий диск? Ну т.е. хочу я в 1000 нитях параллельно читать или писать в разные файлы на диске, будет ли толк, или начнет всё тормозить (имеется ввиду не из-за переключения контекста, а из-за каких-то причин с самим диском)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fsync` и его подвиды требуются, когда приложение хочет получить гарантию, что данные *уже* записаны на физический диск, а не *будут* записаны на диск.

Впрочем, начну лучше со второго вопроса:

> со сколькими параллельными операциями ввода/вывода может работать жесткий диск?

С **одной**. Потому что внутри HDD только один блок головок чтения-записи. И из-за ограничений физических законов нашей вселенной этот блок может одновременно находиться только над одним местом магнитного диска.

И следующее механическое ограничение - магнитные диски вращаются с постоянной скоростью, а читать-писать можно только в одном месте. Значит если мы хотим прочитать сектора в разных местах диска нам требуется:

- спозиционировать на эту дорожку блок головок чтения-записи
- дождаться, пока требуемый сектор не окажется под головкой

Простым математическим подсчётом получаем механический предел в 120 операций в секунду для 7200 rpm дисков (с частотой вращения 7200 оборотов в минуту). Будет меньше операций если надо читать с разных областей диска, т.к. перемещение магнитной головки штука медленная мало того из-за того что механическая операция но должна осуществляться точно (речь о микрометрах), так ещё и в условиях вибрации от собственно самого диска и всех прочих вибраций. Как итог вполне можно попасть не на ту дорожку и придётся перепозиционировать головки ещё раз.

Но зато можно успеть прочитать больше данных, если они идут последовательно в секторах одной дорожки.

В общем, механический диск - штука крайне медлительная и прогресс CPU и оперативной памяти (не имеющих механический частей и потому значительно более быстрых) в прошлом тысячелетии потребовали вводить всевозможные ухищрения. В частности, операционные системы начали кешировать операции чтения и записи данных в неиспользуемых в данный момент выполняющимися программами областях оперативной памяти. И если с чтением всё просто - точно такая же копия лежит в энергонезависимой памяти механических дисков - то с кешированием записи как-то печальнее. Операционная система отвечает приложению "данные записаны", а на самом деле они размещены в оперативной памяти и *будут* записаны когда-нибудь чуть позже, может через несколько секунд. И это замечательно работает и ускоряет все операции с дисков. Вот только при критическом сбое системы (например по питанию) данные будут потеряны.

И чтобы дать приложениям возможность попросить систему именно записать какие-то данные в энергонезависимую память и добавили вызов `fsync`, который синхронизирует кэш записи с дисками.

---

Повторюсь - для механических дисков позиционировать головки операция очень медленная. Поэтому если вы начнёте читать-писать с механическим диском с 1000 потоков - это будет бесконечно долго. При том, ситуацию для вас всеми своими силами постараются сгладить и планировщики ввода-вывода и кэширование файловых операций. Из-за позиционирования головки механические диски могут давать неплохую производительность на последовательных операциях, но производительность случайных операций у механики удручающая.

Но, к счастью, за последние лет 10 сильно подешевела `flash`-память и появились `SSD` диски. Дисками их называют только по привычке, на самом деле никакой механики там уже нет. И параллельная обработка запросов (пусть и за счёт обращений к разным кристаллам памяти) и куда более внушительная производительность по метрике количества операций в секунду (`iops`) - всё возможно. И, вероятно, со временем будут пересмотрены в сторону упрощения и планировщики ввода-вывода (собственно `blk_mq` в ядре `linux` уже) и упрощены другие нагромождения этих десятилетий когда для хранения данных использовалась медлительная механика. У `flash`-памяти своих интересных фокусов тоже хватает (например, есть не 2 операции чтение и запись, а чтение, стирание, запись - запись возможна только в предварительно очищенную страницу. Отсюда выросла необходимость в команде `trim`) - но это уже тема отдельных изысканий.

Comment: Вы пишите про одну операцию при обмене с диском, но это не так даже на механических накопителях. А вот на интерфейсе обмена данными с хостом действительно данные сериализуются -- передаётся только один сектор, поэтому и называются такие устройства *блочными*.

Comment: @0andriy а как физически можно одним блоком головок выполнять несколько разных операций *одновременно*? Устройства они блочные потому что работают только блоками. Например, нельзя прочитать один байт - только сектор целиком.

Comment: @Мелкий, на другом форуме читал про node.js и что делают пул потоков из нескольких десятков потоков для одного жесткого диска... зачем так поступают?

Comment: @Мелкий, а есть ссылки какие-нибудь где б подобные вещи(то, что вы выше описали) объяснялись, а то не могу ничего найти толком

Comment: По каким-то более-менее нормальным описаниям не подскажу. Вот это моё сочинение - краткая выжимка сведений изученных за все 10 лет что я варюсь в IT. Так что где это всё читалось, слышалось и узнавалось - не вспомню.

Comment: По `node.js` же... Лучше про этих странных людей не буду ничего говорить. Может быть смысл был (например, ожиданием io на фоне времени выполнения остальных выполняемых задач можно пренебречь) может быть смысла не было.

Answer (score 2):

1. Например, если  делаете *контрольную точку* вашей программы, т.е. хотите надежно записать текущее состояние файла (его страниц из файлового кэша в ядре) на носитель.
2. Поскольку физические операции ввода/вывода  переупорядочиваются для оптимизации доступа (запросы от файловой системы ставятся в очередь к драйверу устройства) (можете прочесть  в упомянутой книге, см. *лифт Линуса* (видимо вы до этого места еще не дочитали)), то в принципе, ограничительным фактором будет производительность диска (и конечно же, стоимость сохранения контекста в системных вызовах все же не стоит совсем уж игнорировать).

Comment: а по поводу баз данных? там делают этот fsync()?

Comment: @xperious по использованию fsync в базах данных можно отдельное сочинение писать и даже по каждой субд в отдельности. Кратко - используют. И как правило есть куча настроек для выбора баланса между производительностью и устойчивости к отказам (например, делать ли fsync на каждую транзакцию (безопасно) или только по какому-то таймеру (сильно быстрее)).

Comment: @xperious, насколько я понимаю IT, для баз [fdatasync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) должен  быть более востребован. Ну, а журнал можно сразу [открывать](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) с `O_DIRECT`